# Trying to add one last SUM() column to my query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the first query which is producing correct results. What I need is I need to add the sum of values as a last column grouped by `surveyid`. I can't insert `Sum(c.value)` into the first query because it is an aggregate function. I have the correct query as my second query below. I know there's pivot functionality but not sure if it can be used here. I do realize that there will be repetition but that's okay.

'first query

```
SELECT 
   A.PATIENTID, B.STUDENTNUMBER, c.surveyid, 
   convert(varchar, A.CreatedDate, 107), 
   C.QuestionID, C.Value, D.Question
FROM 
   dbo.Survey A, dbo.Patient B, [dbo].[SurveyQuestionAnswer] C, [dbo].[LookupQuestions] D
WHERE 
   A.PATIENTID = B.ID 
   and c.SurveyID = A.ID 
   and c.QuestionID = d.ID 
   and c.questionid <> 10
ORDER BY 
   A.PATIENTID
```

'second query

```
select 
    c.surveyid,SUM(c.value) as scores
from 
    dbo.SurveyQuestionAnswer c
group by 
    c.SurveyID 
order by 
    SurveyID '---not important
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: And also: ***please*** give you tables ***meaningful*** alias names! `FROM dbo.Survey s INNER JOIN dbo.Patient p ON s.PatientId = p.ID INNER JOIN dbo.SurveyQuestionAnswer sqa ON s.ID = sqa.SurveyID .......`  is just **MUCH** easier to read than just those aliasses you're using...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** use `SUM` if you add the `OVER` clause. In this case:

```
SELECT 
   A.PATIENTID, B.STUDENTNUMBER, c.surveyid, 
   convert(varchar, A.CreatedDate, 107), 
   C.QuestionID, C.Value, D.Question,
   SUM(c.Value) OVER(PARTITION BY c.surveyid) scores
FROM 
   dbo.Survey A
INNER JOIN dbo.Patient B
    ON A.PATIENTID = B.ID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SurveyQuestionAnswer] C
    ON c.SurveyID = A.ID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[LookupQuestions] D
    ON c.QuestionID = d.ID 
WHERE 
   c.questionid <> 10
ORDER BY 
   A.PATIENTID
```

Comment: isn't *SUM* *OVER* 2008R2 and later? is this for 2008 plain?

Comment: Thanks guys. This answer produces a different result than marc_s, and marc_s's answer gets the same result as my second query. However for some reason the numbers are off

Comment: @LuisLL `SUM() OVER()` can be used since SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @LuisLL: no, those features have been introduced in SQL Server  **2005** already

Comment: @marc_s Seems like you deleted your answer too quickly. Marin, can you post a data sample to see this difference on results?

Comment: Sure how do I post them? I can take a screenshot but not sure how I can copy and paste data form Sql Server thanks.

Comment: @Marin you can create an example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) (you need to choose SQL Server 2008 as the database, here is an example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/1). In any case, there is a difference on the results from the second query, since there you are not using the filter `questionid <> 10` that you are using on your first query

Comment: Sorry would've taken a long time to get all four tables. I took a picture http://i24.photobucket.com/albums/c25/loqja/marc_s_vs_lamak.png

Comment: @Marin so, did you take into the account what I said before about the score from my answer filtering questionId 10?, because that is a difference

Comment: Oh that's right! QuestionID 10 I'm not sure if it's required or not. I think I forgot to leave it out! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Didn't know about 'sum over' seems pretty interesting, works wonders :) .

Comment: @marc_s & Lamak thanks for pointing this out. What a shame! What a pity I missed the niceties of the aggregate <over clause> for 2 full versions!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT 
   s.PATIENTID, p.STUDENTNUMBER, sqa.surveyid, 
   CONVERT(varchar, s.CreatedDate, 107), 
   sqa.QuestionID, sqa.Value, lq.Question,
   Scores = (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM dbo.SurveyQuestionAnswer s2 WHERE s2.SurveyID = s.ID)
FROM 
   dbo.Survey s
INNER JOIN
   dbo.Patient p ON s.PatientID = p.ID
INNER JOIN
   [dbo].[SurveyQuestionAnswer] sqa ON sqa.SurveyID = s.ID
INNER JOIN 
   [dbo].[LookupQuestions] lq ON sqa.QuestionID = lq.ID
WHERE 
   sqa.questionid <> 10
ORDER BY 
   s.PATIENTID
```

By having a subquery with the `SUM(...)` you should be able to get that sum as a single value and you don't need to use any grouping function